# How can I decide which validation I will execute according to commit values in rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My Environment

```
Rails 3.2.1
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.4.0]
```

I want to change validation method according to the commit value.

For instance, in the following views when 'only_foo' is pushed, I want to check validation only for 'foo', but when 'only_bar' is pushed, I want to check validation only for 'bar'.

```
<%= from_for(@user, :url => "/hoge/") %>
  <%= f.text_field 'foo' %>
  <%= f.text_field 'bar' %>
  <%= f.submit 'only_foo' %>
  <%= f.submit 'only_bar' %>
<% end %>
```

in user model, I want to get the commit value in validate method.

```
validate :foo, :presence => true, :if => :only_foo?
validate :bar, :presence => true, :if => :only_bar?

def only_foo?
  # I want to get the commit value, like this.
  commit == 'only_foo'
end

def only_bar?
  # I want to get the commit value, like this.
  commit == 'only_bar'
end
```

Or are there better practice?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While defining the submit buttons you can associate a name with them

```
<%= f.submit 'only_foo', name: 'foo' %>
<%= f.submit 'only_bar', name: 'bar' %>
```

In your controller action, the `params[:commit]` will contain the name associated with the submit.

You can perhaps assign that as a virtual attribute(i.e. name commit) to an instance of User.
i.e. in the class model have something like `attr_accessor :commit`

Also, Not sure if it helps but you can refactor this slightly to

**UPDATE**

```
validates :foo, :presence => true, if: ->(u) { u.commit == 'foo'}
validates :bar, :presence => true, if: ->(u) { u.commit == 'bar'}
```

Let me know if this helps or whether this needs further elaboration

Comment: user will see two submit buttons :/

Comment: Thats the question :). I.e. seperate validations on clicking one form submit and different on the other

Comment: but why one will confuse his user with two buttons? validation is serverside matter You've parameters add conditional validation!!

Comment: validates :foo, :presence => true, if: ->(u) { u.bar.blank? }

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!
I succeeded to choose validations according to the commit value.

Answer (score 0):

You could go the old school approach of running a method before the .save to check what you want to check, based on any condition you wish.